# Cross contamination

Tags: halal-haram, allah, food, animals, meat

Am I allowed to eat a subway if the employees change their gloves after touching haram foods.

A subway worker touches washed pork and haram beef with gloves on then touches the cheese salads etc. If I tell the worker to change to completely new gloves that’s not touched harman am I allowed to eat the food and get a tuna salad?

Comment: You'd be allowed to do so even if the gloves were not changed.

Comment: Can this be explained as to why it would be allowed even if the gloves are not changed please?

Comment: Because the contamination is neglect able. Also note if you are afraid of it you should avoid eating outside the house at all because none can tell you whether the sandwich didn't come in contact with any pork during the production. This way of thinking is rather extreme.

Comment: Lastly; Even if the worker has touched the cheese and salad with the pork gloves?

Answer (score 0):

The qur'an and the sunnah prophet () teach us to do deeds the best we can. And they also teach us not to go to extremes and overburden ourselves:

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Religion is very easy and whoever **overburdens** himself in his religion will not be able to continue in that way. So **you should not be extremists**, but try to be near to perfection and receive the good tidings that you will be rewarded; and gain strength by worshipping in the mornings, the afternoons, and during the last hours of the nights.
> (Sahih al-Bukhari)

The qur'an teach us that eating pork is haram, but it is nowhere said that pork contaminates any other food by any means.

A contamination by impurity najasah is only given for najasah that has a liquid state such as wine (alcohol). Nevertheless still Islam is a religion of ease and the ruling is that little of najasah has no impact of the impurity of a whole lot. So there's no reason to be too stingy.